# MySQL INSERT ... WHERE syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't find the reason for the error here, help please

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( name, city, country, phone, twitter, bio, gender ) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$city."', '".$country."', '".$phone."', '".$twitter."', '".$bio."', '".$gender."') WHERE username = '".$username."'";
```

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username = ''" at line 1

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, are you using MySQL or [MS] SQL Server?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username = ''" at line 1

Comment: Remove the `WHERE username = '".$username."'"`, it seems useless in your case. 
There's `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE` statement in case you need to insert data retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where clauses are not part of the Insert statements. You cannot INSERT...WHERE

Comment: ooh, thanks, so how do i insert to a particular row based on session?

Comment: You don't insert into rows, you insert into tables. Are you thinking that you need to UPDATE an already existing record? If so, read the documentation on UPDATE statements instead of INSERT statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify a `WHERE` clause, you probably want an `UPDATE` statement instead:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```